# Obtain data from QuerySnapshot

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I want to obtain data from my cloud firestore. The collection is called 'feedback'. The following code is working

```
  constructor(private fireStore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.fireStore.collection('feedback')
                  .get()
                  .subscribe((item: firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) => {
      this.feedbackItems = item.docs.map((dataItem: firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) => dataItem.data());
    });
  }
```

with the import

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

However `this.feedbackItems` is now an array of my feedback object from the cloud firestore. Is it possible to obtain the results as an observable? 
What is the professional way to obtain the data?

I found several solutions on stackoverflow, however some functions were not available (I guess because a different library or JavaScript is used?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to obtain the results as an observable?

You can import `map` from the `rxjs/operators` to alter the response. You can then assign it to some observable.

```
this.feedbackItemObservable = this.fireStore.collection('feedback')
  .get()
  .pipe(map((item:firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) => {
    return item.docs.map((dataItem: firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) => dataItem.data());
  }));
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. All the solutions I saw called `.get().map()` which is not available for me.. Can you tell me where I can find the documentation for such operations? I was kinda lost while searching on my own.

Comment: @Jens - `get` returns an Observable which is from the `rxjs` library. If you want to know what is available on that type I would start there with their documentation. See [reactivex.io - operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) and [Learnrxjs - operators/](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/)